# Autocompletion of a variable name while Python debugging

Tags: python, auto-complete-mode, debug

Suppose I want to debug Python script in Emacs. `M-x pdb` `run pdb like this pdb script name.py`. Next I'd like to examine a variable. I type `p` and first letters of a variable name, then press `Tab` and instead of completion of the variable name cursor moves right. Ho to achieve completion of a variable name on `Tab` press while debugging Pyhon in Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used `M-x pdb` on and off for quite some time now, and while I would love to be corrected on this, unfortunately I don't think it supports tab completion.

I have recently started playing with [RealGUD](https://github.com/realgud/realgud/), and if you use this package with `ipdb` instead of `pdb` you will get some really nice features ***including tab completion***.

[image]

`M-x pdb` is nice because it is built in, but I personally have never found it to be satisfactory for my needs.

Comment: I installed realgud through melpa (GNU Emacs 24.3.1, Ubuntu 14.04). `realgud:ipdb` puts a lot of unreadable garbage in buffer and tab completion doesn't work either. It posts the message `no prompt found or comint-pomp-regexp not set properly`.

Comment: @AlexeyReshetnyak I am not sure what the problem is. I am on Emacs 24.5.1 and Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. I included a screenshot to what it looks like for me out of the box. Includes nicely formatted context for where you are in the script, which I like. Maybe a little busy for some though. The only dependency I installed was `python-ipdb` through `apt`.

Comment: elethan, I installed the latest version of Emacs (25.1.50), but it didn't solve the problem. Still have garbage in console. Anyway thank you for the answer it might be useful to someone.